# how to delete row for a given date index value

Tags: pandas, delete-row

I tried below but was not able to delete the row against the given date...

I tried the below syntax (line 2 below) but it still does not delete the row for index value = '2016-01-25"

```
norm_data = normalize_data(data, '^NSEI')
norm_data.drop(pd.to_datetime('2016-01-25'))
print norm_data.head(50)


              ^NSEI_price    ^NSEI_vol
Date                                

2016-01-20     0.938136     1.674833
2016-01-21     0.933965     1.786934
2016-01-22     0.952659     1.701559
2016-01-25     0.954417  1211.261321
2016-01-27     0.954622     1.392725
```

Comment: assign back or pass `inplace=True` the `drop` is not inplace. e.g. `norm_data = norm_data.drop(pd.to_datetime('2016-01-25'))` or `norm_data.drop(pd.to_datetime('2016-01-25'), inplace=True)` see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

Comment: Ok I got it...I had to re-assign the second line to norm_data

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
norm_data.drop(pd.to_datetime('2016-01-25'))
```

Returns a copy of norm_data. It does not alter the norm_data df. To change it, you can use:

```
# Setting inplace flag to True
norm_data.drop(pd.to_datetime('2016-01-25'), inplace=True)
```

Or the less efficient, but easier to remember:

```
# Re-assign df to copy of df
norm_data = norm_data.drop(pd.to_datetime('2016-01-25'))
```